# Issues programming an FPGA by comp sci major, unexpected output

Tags: verilog, fpga

**Context:**
I am a computer science major, filling a gap left by our computer engineering guy. I am in school, and this is part of my senior project. I am attempting to program an FPGA for use in an electronic board game being created by my group. The FPGA is simply an IO extender to the Raspberry Pi, which controls all logic. The verilog code below is running on an Altera Max V 570 devkit, with intentions of migrating to a Max V 40 for the production units. Each FPGA will control a group of 4 game tiles, and there will be 4 groups of tiles for the final product.

**Problem:**
I am creating an FPGA that will interface with a raspberry pi to control MOSFETs (now LEDs) in our system. The issues I am having is that, no matter what command I send to the tile, the LEDs are always toggled like so:

for tile0, only the 0th LED will toggle
for tile1, only the 1st LED will toggle
for tile2, only the 2nd LED will toggle
for tile3, only the 3rd LED will toggle

Here is a link to a photo of this in action:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7P773tnBnRybHhGRmZMX3hScGFrNXpKUDN2c0tBbkFZaTVJ
(Ignore the final LED in each group, that will be input from a capacitive sensor)

This is true of the LED toggle command (2'b11 in code below) and for the solenoid toggle (2'b01 in code below).

During simulation with Altera ModelSim, everything works perfectly! But with everything hooked up to the breadboard, I see the situation above.

**My thoughts on the problem**
I initially thought the issue was with assigning to the same register I was reading from, but I added another step (haphazardly...) to read the register, then assign, but I saw worse behavior (LEDs would not toggle). HELP! :)

Here is my verilog code:

```
module comm_protocol(clock, bus, t0, t1, t2, t3, t0cap, t1cap, t2cap, t3cap, capOut);

parameter [1:0] my_address = 2'b11;


input clock;
input [3:0] bus;

output reg [4:0] t0;
output reg [4:0] t1;
output reg [4:0] t2;
output reg [4:0] t3;

input wire t0cap, t1cap, t2cap, t3cap;
output reg capOut;

reg start;
reg [1:0] tickCounter;

reg gotFpgaAddress;
reg [1:0] fpgaAddress;
reg[1:0] tileAddress;

reg gotCommand;
reg [3:0] command;

initial begin

    start <= 0;

    t0 <= 5'b11111;
    t1 <= 5'b11111;
    t2 <= 5'b11111;
    t3 <= 5'b11111;

end


always @ (posedge clock) begin

    // check if we have recieved the start condition, which is just a positive edge on the clock
    if (~start) begin

        start <= 1;
        tickCounter <= 0;
        gotFpgaAddress <= 0;
        gotCommand <= 0;

    end
    else begin // we have received the start condition, so continue into the logic

        // increment the counter
        // this counter controls when a reset of the logic is performed
        // the entire protocol should take place in 4 cycles, so when our counter hits 3 we are done
        tickCounter <= tickCounter + 1;
        if (tickCounter == 3) begin

            start <= 0;

        end
        else begin // no reset, continue into logic

            // here, we will read the address of the fpga the pi is talking to
            // first check if we have recieved the address or not
            if (~gotFpgaAddress) begin

                fpgaAddress <= bus[3:2]; //[3:0];
                tileAddress <= bus[1:0];

                gotFpgaAddress <= 1;
                //gotTileAddress <= 1;

            end
            else begin // we got the address, now compare it to see if it matches our address

                if (fpgaAddress == my_address) begin

                    // the message is intended for us, so next we check if the command has been received
                    if (~gotCommand) begin

                        //tileAddress <= bus[3:0];
                        command <= bus;
                        gotCommand <= 1;

                    end
                    else begin  // we have received the command, now decode it and perform the action

                        // decode the command that has been sent
                        // leading 11xx : toggle an led specified by the 2 least significant bits
                        // leading 00xx : read from the capactive sensor and write it onto the bus
                        // leading 01xx : toggle the solenoid for the popup

                        // implement logic to toggle leds
                        if (command[3:2] == 2'b11) begin

                            // route to appropriate tile
                            case (tileAddress)

                                // tile 0
                                2'b00: begin 
                                    case (command[1:0])
                                        2'b00: t0[0] <= ~t0[0];
                                        2'b01: t0[1] <= ~t0[1];
                                        2'b10: t0[2] <= ~t0[2];
                                        2'b11: t0[3] <= ~t0[3];
                                    endcase
                                end 
                                // tile 1
                                2'b01: begin
                                    case (command[1:0])
                                        2'b00: t1[0] <= ~t1[0];
                                        2'b01: t1[1] <= ~t1[1];
                                        2'b10: t1[2] <= ~t1[2];
                                        2'b11: t1[3] <= ~t1[3];
                                    endcase
                                end 
                                // tile 2
                                2'b10: begin
                                    case (command[1:0])
                                        2'b00: t2[0] <= ~t2[0];
                                        2'b01: t2[1] <= ~t2[1];
                                        2'b10: t2[2] <= ~t2[2];
                                        2'b11: t2[3] <= ~t2[3];
                                    endcase
                                end
                                // tile 3
                                2'b11: begin
                                    case (command[1:0])
                                        2'b00: t3[0] <= ~t3[0];
                                        2'b01: t3[1] <= ~t3[1];
                                        2'b10: t3[2] <= ~t3[2];
                                        2'b11: t3[3] <= ~t3[3];
                                    endcase
                                end

                            endcase

                        end
                        // implement logic to read from the capacitive sensor and write it onto the bus
                        else if (command[3:2] == 2'b00) begin

                            case (tileAddress)

                                2'b00: capOut <= t0cap;
                                2'b01: capOut <= t1cap;
                                2'b10: capOut <= t2cap;
                                2'b11: capOut <= t3cap;

                            endcase

                        end
                        // implement logic to toggle the solenoid
                        else if (command[3:2] == 2'b01) begin

                            case (tileAddress)

                                2'b00: t0[4] <= ~t0[4];
                                2'b01: t1[4] <= ~t1[4];
                                2'b10: t2[4] <= ~t2[4];
                                2'b11: t3[4] <= ~t3[4];

                            endcase

                        end

                    end

                end

            end

        end

    end    

end


endmodule
```

**BONUS**
Currently I have consumed 42 logic elements, if anyone can give me pointers on how to reduce this to exactly 40 LEs or less, I will be eternally grateful! Not a big deal, the 80 element Max V is only 70 cents more than the MaxV40

Comment: Did you get any warnings during fpga compilation? There are few places which looks suspicious to me. 1) there is no proper reset. initial block might not be working in fpga. 2) you declare your ports as 'reg' which is not necessarily a well behaved concept. Might have connectivity issues in higher level hierarchies and a difference in simulation/fpga behavior.

Comment: That's a lot of code to read in a 2-minute coffee break. One obvious thing is `command` - when do you assign it, and when do you read it? Is it in 2 different clock cycles? Would you expect that to work and, if so, why? Draw a timing diagram, and then code from the diagram; your control flow looks wrong. Also make sure you understand what a non-blocking assignment (`<=`) does.

Comment: @Serge I get warnings, but nothing that would give me any clues as to why this isn't functioning correctly. Just that timing files are missing and so on.

Comment: @EML command is assigned after the fpga address and tile address is received. At the next clock cycle, the contents of command are used, so I'm not assigning and trying to use it in the same cycle. Also, there is plenty of time between clock cycles, right now I'm manually toggling everything from a shell on the pi (using python and pigpio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found the issue in your python code. One thing that might have helped is adding one more input pin as a qualifier to sampling the bus. Otherwise would will need make sure all FPGAs are fully synchronized.

Now for your bonus question:

Without change any behavior of your code you can eliminate 3 flops (`start`, `gotFpgaAddress`, and `gotCommand`) and a tiny bit of logic gates by converting `tickCounter` into a FSM. I noticed that when `tickCounter` is 0, you are always in an initileal/reset state. When it is 1, you are getting the address. When it is 2, you may collect the command if it is the target fpga address. And when it is 3, you toggle the LEDs if at the target fpga address.

```
localparam INIT=2'b0, GETADDR=2'b01, GETCMD=2'b10, TOGGLELED=2'b11;
reg [1:0] state;

reg [1:0] fpgaAddress;
reg [1:0] tileAddress;
reg [3:0] command;

initial begin
    state = INIT; // Note: initial blocks should use blocking statements
    t0 = 5'b11111;
    t1 = 5'b11111;
    t2 = 5'b11111;
    t3 = 5'b11111;
end

always @ (posedge clock) begin
  case(state)
    INIT :
      begin
        state <= GETADDR;
        // technically this is a dummy state, but needed to match behavior
      end
    GETADDR :
      begin
        state <= GETCMD;
        fpgaAddress <= bus[3:2];
        tileAddress <= bus[1:0];
      end
    GETCMD :
      begin
        state <= TOGGLELED;
        /* No output is effected in this state,
         * so it doesn't matter what the address is.
         * Preventing assignment to command would add logic.
         */
        command <= bus;
      end
    TOGGLELED :
      begin
        state <= INIT;
        // Here we care about the address
        if (fpgaAddress == MY_ADDRESS) begin 
          // ... your assignments to t0-t3 here ...
          /* There are tricks to reduce the number of lines of code here,
           * but nothing I can immanently think of that will reduce gate count.
           */
        end
      end
  endcase
end
```

If really want to squeeze the area, you can bring it down to two states by removing the `INIT` and `GETCMD` states. Just remember that `bus` is now your `command` in the `TOGGLELED` state. Also note that this changes your design from a 4 cycles down to 2 cycles. So you would need to change stimulus (your python code) as well.

If you add the qualifier input pin I mentioned above then it is a tweak to the state assignment (ex: `if (start_fsm) begin state <= NEXT_STATE ; /*... other stuff ...*/ end else begin state <= CURRENT_STATE; end`).

---

One another topic, your module header is written in an somewhat outdated style called Non-ANSI. A more strict version of Non-ANSI is required with Verilog-1995 (ex `output [4:0] t0;` `reg[4:0] t0;` instead of `output reg[4:0] t0;`) but has lost popularity since Verilog-2001 became wildly supported. The modern header style is referred to as ANSI. With the ANSI style you declare the port order, direction, and type on the same line (where Non-ANSI required 2 to 3 separate lines). It is cleaner an less prone to typos.

```
module comm_protocol #(parameter [1:0] MY_ADDRESS = 2'b11) (
    input clock,
    input [3:0] bus,

    output reg [4:0] t0,
    output reg [4:0] t1,
    output reg [4:0] t2,
    output reg [4:0] t3,

    input wire t0cap, t1cap, t2cap, t3cap,
    output reg capOut );
```

Comment: You are amazing! I am going to implement your suggestions in the next few days, I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: Final outcome: 37 LEs used! You just saved me from purchasing the 80 element MaxV.... 0.7USD * 4 fpga per game board * 15 game boards = 42USD saved! Rock on you beautiful pink bunny!

Answer (score 0):

*Sigh*

Found the problem, it was with the python code controlling the whole damn thing. I reused the variable for sending the addresses, and mistakenly sent that as the command as well...

BUT IT WORKS!!